# C# & SQL Server : query takes long time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and getting categories list and adding subcategories list to each category. My query takes long time. Thanks for answers.

```
// Create Sub Cat List 
List<CategoryVM> catlist = (List<CategoryVM>)catServices.GetAll();

for (int i = 0; i < catlist.Count(); i++)
{
    List<SubCategoryVM> subCatById = subCatServices.GetAll().Where(x => x.Category_Id == catlist[i].Id).ToList();

    foreach (SubCategoryVM item in subCatById)
    {
        catlist[i].SubCategoryVM.Add(item);
    }
}

ViewData["CatAndSubcatList"] = catlist;
```

And my service code is:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryVM> GetAll()
{
    var data = ProjectMapper.ConvertToVMList<IEnumerable<CategoryVM>>(_CategoryRepository.GetAll());
    return (IEnumerable<CategoryVM>)data;
}
```

Comment: As per Sergei Zinovyev answer, your code is slow very likely because you have many items (and need 1 additional query for every item). Given that, storing these items in ViewState does not seems the best choice. You will have a lot of data going back and forth from your server to browser.

Comment: In the first look, I can suggest you prevent to convert query results to list when you want to iterate on them. But there is some information you have to give. You have a function that is not specified what is happening in: `GetAll()`. What ORM are you using? How are tables related to each other?

Comment: My Subcat count is 226. Category count is 22. I use Entity Framework generic repository for CRUD

Comment: Category Table : Id-Title | Sub Category Table : Id-Title-CatId

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code for `catServices.GetAll()` and `subCatServices.GetAll()` so we can help you

Comment: Suggestions: 1- as I mentioned before, don't convert IEnumerable to List; It's a heavy process and not necessary. 2. As @CetinBasoz said, edit your service method or add a new method which uses DbContext. The bottle-neck is your service method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting Categories and then adding the subcategories in a loop, use LINQ and get them in a single call. We don't have your model, so this sample is by guess:

```
var catlist = dbContext.CategoryVM.Include("SubCategoryVM").ToList();
```

This is your code edited. Instead of getting all Categories and then getting all subcategories again and again in a loop, it gets the lists from database just once and does the rest locally:

```
//Create Sub Cat List 
List<CategoryVM> catlist = (List<CategoryVM>)catServices.GetAll();
List<SubCategoryVM> subCats = subCatServices.GetAll();

for (int i = 0; i < catlist.Count(); i++)
{
    foreach (SubCategoryVM item in subCatById)
    {
        catlist[i].SubCategoryVM.AddRange(subCats.Where(x => x.Category_Id == catlist[i].Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Entity Framework generic repository for CRUD so I use services to get datas. Not using dbcontext in controller.

Comment: @CihanKalmaz, then use dbcontext (Or in your repository create a method to get with subcategories).

Comment: @CihanKalmaz, I am sorry your code simply is getting all and converting to another type. What I am saying add a method that gets all as an IQueryable and also includes subcategories.

Comment: How can i write this method?

Comment: @CihanKalmaz, with EF simply write it as I did in the code. I don't know your EF model, you may need to change entity and navigational property names (those names are not standard names that EF generation tool produces).

Comment: @CihanKalmaz, if EF sounds to be complex (sometimes it does, like for this simple case), you could simply get all the Categories and Subcategories independently once and connect locally. I am going to write code for you.

Comment: @CihanKalmaz, edited the code (your code really slightly modified).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You run sql inside loop so it may run 1000 times. That is why it is slow. I call it 1+N issue. Network connection (read Input/Output (IO) operations) is usually slow.

You need to change your code to get what you want from SQL Server in a 1 or 2 query (not N). Then you can have a loop to process your in memory data.

Answer (score -1):

This is loop issue. GetAll(): i think this method is getting all record then you filter from In-memory collection. Create generic method to execute query on server side.